# How to integrate the above expression?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \sin(1+|x|+|x^2|+|x^3|)\,dx$$

How to integrate the above expression? I am trying to integrate by factoring $(1+|x|+|x^2|+|x^3|$), so after factoring I am getting $\frac{(|x^4|-1)}{(|x|-1)}$. So finally I am getting this expression to be $\sin(\frac{(|x^4|-1)}{(|x|-1)})$. But how to approach further? Kindly help me out with this question.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note $|x^2|=x^2$.

Comment: @CroCo Only assuming x is a subset of the reals right?

Comment: @Zachiah yes I assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$. As this is an element, I'm not sure what a subsect in this context means.

Comment: [WA doesn't seem to have a solution.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+sin%281%2B%7Cx%7C%2B%7Cx%5E2%7C%2B%7Cx%5E3%7C%29)